# Pitch analysis Audio Unit

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I am developing an audio application for macOS that I would like to use to analyse the notes in a given section of music.

I am happy to work from an analysis of the frequencies in a given section then translate these frequencies to musical pitch if needed.

Is there an existing Audio Unit that will help me accomplish this?

If this is too broad a question, please suggest a way of identifying a suitable Audio Unit. A search on the web turns up very many spectrum analyser Audio Units, so advice on identifying one and what attributes I should be looking for would be appreciated.

If this is the wrong place to be asking about Audio Units at all, also please advise.

Comment: Search for "pitch" on here, and you'll find dozens of question like yours. The answer is: it's extremely hard to reconstruct the notes from a played piece of music, because it's simply not that invertibly a problem.

Comment: I found https://aubio.org/ which looks like it might be useful.